# How to implement a 'before' hook that can output an alternative response?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

Need to do some authentication checks before deciding what content to display. Ideally, I'd like to have a restrictive base handler, that would implement the "before" hook that could show an alternative content, instead of the requested content.

```
class Restrictive(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.is_logged_in():
            self.response.write('not logged in')
            self.abort(200)
    def is_logged_in(self):
         return False
```

But this won't output the response, only headers. What is the proper way of aborting the requested handler and showing alternative content?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote this decorator once.

```
def authenticated(handler):
    """
        Decorator for checking if there's a user associated with the current session.
        Will also fail if there's no session present.
    """
    def check_login(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.is_logged_in():
           self.response.write('not logged in')
           return self.error(403) 
        else:
           return handler(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return check_login
```

You can then decorate your methods if they need to be authenticated.

```
class MyHandler:
    @authenticated
    def get(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. However, I'm more interested in flushing the response and preventing requested handler execution.

Comment: when I try to write a decorator this way, I just get 'can't call NoneType'

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches

One would be to set up wsgi middleware - wraps you app, and it can check the auth before the handler is actually called.  http://pythonweb.org/projects/webmodules/doc/0.5.3/html_multipage/lib/example-command-program-flow.html

Alternately use decorator on the method that checks auth before the method is called

Either option can then return the correct status, and your actual handler doesn't need to worry about that sort of logic.